# print 1 to 5 and even and odd in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a html page which satisfy below requirement-
1. print 1 to 5 with another array
2. take number input from textbox then print on page whether it is Even or Odd.

I have create a page but it is not working as desired.

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <input type="number" id="myNumber">
        <button onclick="oddOrEven()">Try it</button>
        <input type="text" name="result" id="result" readonly="true"/>
            <SCRIPT>    
            var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
            var myObjects = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"];
            var text = "";
            var myObjectsList =""
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                text += numbers[i] + " : " + myObjects[i] + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

            function oddOrEven() {
            var value = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
            var res = if((value % 2) == 0) {"Even"} else {"Odd"}*/
            //if(value % 2 == 0) document.write("Even")
            //document.write(value);
            //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
            readonly.value=res;
            }
            //document.write("Hello World!");

        </SCRIPT>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Could someone please help me with the code.

Comment: Define "not working as desired"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the updated solution

```js
            
            var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
            var myObjects = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"];
            var text = "";
            var myObjectsList =""
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                text += numbers[i] + " : " + myObjects[i] + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

            function oddOrEven() {
            var value = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
            var res = value % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd";
            document.getElementById("result").value=res;
            }
            //document.write("Hello World!");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
        <input type="number" id="myNumber">
        <button onclick="oddOrEven()">Try it</button>
        <input type="text" name="result" id="result" readonly/>
```

Updated code

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var myObjects = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"];
var text = "";
var myObjectsList =""
var i;
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    text += numbers[i] + " : " + myObjects[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

function oddOrEven() {
var value = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
var res = value % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="number" id="myNumber">
<button onclick="oddOrEven()">Try it</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Update2
Replace

```
<p id="result"></p>
```

with

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you Lalit. I implemented the code and it is working. Now how to print Even/Odd in the page body instead of in a textbox.

Comment: the even/odd is printing in the new page. Is it possible to print it in the same page without using textbox.

Comment: Updated please check, and mark your best answer check.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the way you are assigning `res`, it should be as follows:

```
var res = value % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd";
```

Alternatively you can use an if statement if you want like so:

```
var res = "Odd";
if(value % 2 == 0) {
    res = "Even";
}
```

---

In addition, there is also an issue with this line:

```
readonly.value=res;
```

In this case, `readonly` does not exist. You probably mean to do this:

```
document.getElementById("result").value = res;
```

Comment: Thank you musefin. Could you also let me know how i can print even/odd on the body of the page rather than in a textbox?

Comment: try `document.write` again

Comment: If i put `doument.write` then the previous content get erased and only even/odd get printed based on value.

Comment: Well you should probably avoid that anyway. Whats wrong with the text box approach? Or updating the `p` element, like this: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;`

Comment: There is nothing wrong in printing that in another textbox and its work well. For my learning purpose i wanted to know whether we can print it in the same page.